# How to have full control over terminal with networking?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

Is there a way to have full control over the terminal via networking. For example, I have a server and client written in C, I want to send a command like `rm file` or `cd directory` to the server (server in this case is a linux computer) and get the terminal output back to the client. I have it currently working with `ls` using `popen()` but it cannot change directories or do other complex commands. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps using `fork()` `pipe()` and other functions in order to use any command and get full output from terminal.

Comment: I don't know the specific trade-offs and assumptions you're making for your project. But if I were to do something like this, I would probably just ask the program to use 'ssh' to securely log in and run a command. e.g.: "ssh remote-server '/bin/ls'".

Comment: @MultimediaMike Basically I want to have an exact replica of the linux terminal via networking. Such as I can do commands like `ls` and it will send results to client, or `cat > file` and the server and client will listen for input and make a file with what you input, etc etc.

Comment: @alexis It is the most appealing project and I would love to get it working.

Comment: Sounds good, then my advice is to choose one aspect to implement (presumably the networking), and use standard facilities for the rest.

Comment: @alexis I finished the networking, but I do not know how to go about the terminal control part for getting output from terminal.

Comment: check the telnet protocol on wikipedia, it's what you want...

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is done by SSH.

> For example, I have a server and client written in C, I want to send a command like rm file or cd directory to the server (server in this case is a linux computer) and get the terminal output back to the client.

I strongly discourage to implement such a functionality yourself. The odds are high, that your own approach will have several security issues.

SSH is the de-facto standard for remote terminals, has strong encryption, real world tested authentication and strong maintenance support. Also there are excellent open source implementations, like OpenSSH.

Comment: I am not worried or interested in the security issues involved with making this. I am doing this for learning and to have an interesting tool laying around for future use. I appreciate your concerns though.

Comment: @HurricaneChris: When it comes to network programming, security issues are the foremost problem. You simply can not ignore the issue because this is "for learning". As soon as you attach something to a network socket, and be it for learning, you must consider security; in case of a learning experience, you also learn about security then. The three aspects of security are confidentiality, integrity and availability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, since it is so important is there any references or tutorials you would recommend?

Comment: @HurricaneChris: I'd start with the book "Security Engineering" (legally available online for free) http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html – there are no single silver bullets to address this topic and this book does a great job in getting a newbie on this started. Then I can recommend the texts of Bruce Schneier and of course reading the various hacker releases like http://phrack.com (always read those with an appropriate amount of grain of salt).

Comment: @HurricaneChris: When learning network programming, don't start with a remote shell. Start with something simple, like a chat and then try to break the protocol. Then add things that easily break, for example you may want to add transmission of images files then displayed on the remote end. The odds are high, that you build something vulnerable. Regarding your question about remote shells, well, its of course worthwile to understand how they make a terminal on the other end. I recommend you read up on the pty(7) API http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pty.7.html

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, i will definitely be reading the things you linked, and as for starting easy, i already have the chat done, but i wanted to make it into a remote shell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact set-up is, but why not just fork off a shell on the remote side? You can then do anything that can be done from the commandline.

If a real, interactive connection is an option, look into pty's ("pseudo-ttys"). It's how real terminal applications work.

Comment: My set up is a archbang laptop and a windows desktop, I have the networking completed, but I want to be able to use the terminal of the laptop from the desktop with full functionality.

Comment: Fork off a remote shell. The `cat > file` notation is part of the shell's command language. If you try to implement it yourself, you're creating your own shell and that's just too many wheels reinvented at once.

Comment: Once I have the shell `fork()`ed how do I go about getting the output from the shell after doing commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the output from `ls` then you are on the right path.

The next thing is to be able to send the *input*, not very different from the output. You can use the command `cat` to check if you are doing it right, both input and output at the same time.

Then, just run your favourite shell command, for example `bash`, and you can write the commands to the input stream and read the output from each command.

Note that `cd` is not a program; it is a shell command, so you have to run a shell for it to mean anything at all. The same is true for redirection and the other complexities it seems you want to do.

PS: Please be aware that this may be a serious security issue and that you should seriously consider an already-made alternative, such as ssh, as others have said.

Comment: I am currently using `popen()` for the `ls` command, but it will not work for other commands. For example, when using `cd Documents/` the i receive `/bin/sh: Documents/: is a directory` and it does not change to it or anything.

Comment: Ah, but `popen` cannot read and write at the same time! You have to do the `pipe` and `fork` thing yourself!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! Can you go into further detail as to how I should go about fixing this issue then?

Comment: Well, I'm sure there are plenty of resources in the Internet of how to do this, but the idea is: 1) Use `pipe()` to create the input pipe; 2) Use `pipe()` again to create the output pipe; 3) `fork()`; 4) in the child process close the write end of the input pipe and the read end of the output pipe; 5) in the child do `exec()`; 6) in the parent close the read end of the input pipe and the write end of the output pipe; 7) in the parent read and write from /to the pipes and don't forget to `wait()` for the child when it finishes or it will convert into a zombi!

Comment: I understand the process of `piping` and `forking` but as far as `exec()` goes, does it do commands in the terminal and keep the output from the terminal? This is my main problem I am facing

Comment: Yes, that's what sells are for: they read commands from the input and run them with the output shared between them and itself.

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit more please?

Comment: He means "shells". As for exec, it retains all the open file descriptors of the parent process (including stdin and stdout). There is no relevant concept of a "terminal". Read about the exec system call, a.k.a. `exec (2)`.

Comment: @alexis I read the man page for it but it is still unclear to what the function does. Can you provide a link or explain it to me?